# Breaking Horizontal Rule Running Across Adjacent Columns in a Table

Tags: tables, rules

Is there any way to force a break in the horizontal rule running across two adjacent cells of a table. To be more precise, here is what I'm looking for:

[image]

Notice how I wish the lines to fall short of the left and right borders of the table as well. I would really appreciate it if someone can provide a simple and compact solution.

This is the usual scenario for comparing against:

[image]

Here is the simple code for quick access:

```
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{C1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C2} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C3} \\ \cline{2-3} \cline{4-5}
                    & C21 & C22              & C31 & C32            \\ \hline
Val1                & Val2 & Val3            & Val4 & Val5 \\ 

\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Please add a minimal working example.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill - Will keep that in mind from now on. Thank you very much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [the `booktabs` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs):

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{C1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C2} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C3} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
                    & C21 & C22              & C31 & C32            \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
Val1                & Val2 & Val3            & Val4 & Val5 \\ 

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```